# css media max and min width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `div` tags, which I want to show only one of them depending on the screen size,

but for a specific screen size (in my case 699px) both of them are shown and I can't understand why.

Anyone know why?

More specific, I don't understand why the second div is shown on screen size of 699px.

Further more, if I change the `max-width` to `698px` the second div is not shown for screen size of 698px.

Any ideas why?

In case it matters, my project is build with React v17

html:

```
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
```

css:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .first {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .second{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

## ====================
Edit

Regarding the answer of @Imran Rafique

[image]

Comment: show the content of your `head` tag

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: It works for me too. And it's strange that it doesn't work for you. Look in the object inspector. Maybe something interrupts your media query.

Comment: What do you mean by object inspector..?

Comment: browser object inspector (F12)

Comment: oh ahaha I know it as the developer tools.. no problem in the media query, it just get into action on 698px instead of 699px..

Comment: do you have any other media queries related to these blocks (.first, .second)?

Comment: no.. only those 2..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```css
.first, .second {
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .first {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .second{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='first'><h1>first</h1></div>
<div class='second'><h1>Second</h1></div>
```

Comment: In your answer both of the ```divs``` are shown on 699px.. You didn't do anything different than me

Comment: @guy working perfectly on my side as you wanted, where are you testing it ?

Comment: chrome Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit) using the developer tools. same for firefox 82.0.2 (64-bit). I added  a screen shot to my question

Comment: @guy that's strange https://i.ibb.co/pPvcMq1/Untitled.png working like a charm on my side

Comment: Yea that's why I'm really confused.. Have no idea what is wrong..